# How To Keep Track when background services have executed

Tags: xamarin.forms, background-service

I am new to Xamarin, what I am trying to close that gap on a pattern used for messages. How do pages/view models know if a background service sent a message before that viewmodel was instantiated? How do I know if a background service IS running or just finished running a few mins ago or did the background service fail?

Scenario:
User on a Login Page logs in. We start a few background services

1. Download latest list of pdf files
2. Pull list of products available
3. Download a bunch of images
4. etc...

the the UI will open the persons' profile page and subscribe to each of the events and display data from the database once completed.

In the navigation menu you can go to the products available page, when that pages loads I shows you all products available. How does the ProductsAvailableViewModel know if all products were downloaded, or did it fail to download. The message could have been sent prior to the viewmodel object instantiation.

I was thinking of solving the problem this way:
Have a table in the SQLite database that tracks all the messages sent by all services. A view model can query the events to see if a service is still working on pulling data, or if it recently failed and needs to be retried before showing any data on the screen.

Is there a common pattern practice that is being used out there? I don't want to fall into some anti-pattern process which will have to be re-written.

Comment: MessagingCenter can help you but also do some looking around in Stephen Cleary’s Stackoverflow answers, the man literally wrote the book on async/await and background tasks.